# 4000 characters limit on Developer Story

Tags: support, feature-request, developer-story

Recntly I decided to make some changes in my CV. I wanted to modify a "Position" entry by adding some stuff about the interesting projects I worked on.
However, when attempting to save my input I was greeted by a **"value cannot be longer than 4000 characters"**. Bummer... 
 
I would really like to keep everything I want to write about those projects in a single entry. Is it possible to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: Respect the time of the reader.  This is going to be read by a busy PM or team lead, he won't have time to read a book.  The more succinct you make it, the greater the odds he'll read it all and still has time left to send you an invitation.

Answer (score 4):

You could add an "Other" entry per project, but, as the "summary" field in there suggests: "Keep it short"
A developer story / CV really shouldn't be a wall of text to dig through.

Comment: I thought about the "Other" entry. But you can't set an end date on those. I should have mentionned in my question that I'm using markdown to format the text, so that the summary of each project is highlighted while the details are written in a more discreet way. That makes it easy to scroll throught. And if the readers want to, they can learn more about one particular project by looking at the description written in fine print. But yeah, I guess I am trying to make apple juice with a toaster. I'll just add some "Other" entries for the time being.